# DaVinci Resolve 15 view multiple tracks at once

Tags: davinci-resolve, playback

So I have been looking for an answer for long and have not found any. I want to view multiple video tracks separately. The idea is that I have video sources from multiple cameras, I want to sync them in the timeline, each one in separate track, but then I want to see them all at the same time for me to decide which clip from which camera I use in the final product. I would like to use it for 2 to 4 cameras.

Currently running Resolve 15 and I am aware of Resolve 16 having new "Cut" workspace but I have not tested it.

If you have any ideas how to do this in Resolve I would be very grateful. However, a working, easy to use, third party program would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the Multi-Cam feature is for. You can see this Tutorial: [How to use Multicam in Resolve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4T0hz5Upk7o) in it, you can preview all cameras at once. Keep in mind that this is quite perfomance intensif. Make sure to use Proxy to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I was looking for it but did not know how to name it.